# pandoc doesnt generate latex equations during .md to .html conversion

Tags: latex3, pandoc, html, markdown

I'm using pandoc to convert a .md file with latex equations into .html

```
pandoc sample_equations.md -o test_today.html
```

This is one such equation in `sample_equations.md`

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \nu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}
\end{equation}
```

The problem is that the generated `test_today.html` does not have latex equations as well as tables(output is just text in this case). But converting the same `.md` file into a `.pdf` I get all the desired equations and tables. Also, if I use `ReText` and generate the `.html` file, everything is fine.

Can someone point-out what the issue is with pandoc? Thanks

Comment: @close voters: MathJax is off-topic but Pandoc is on-topic so this question is fine in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

So I have found the solution for `.md` with math equations to `.html` conversion with `pandoc`:

```
pandoc --toc --standalone --mathjax -t sample_equations.md -o test_today.html --metadata pagetitle="todaystest"
```

Also, explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55106932/8547163

Comment: It's also in pandoc's manual: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math-rendering-in-html